# Get PostGIS version

Tags: postgresql, postgis

How can I find out which version of PostGIS I have?

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Since some of the functions depend on other libraries like GEOS and proj4 you might want to get their versions too. Then use:

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

Comment: don't forget to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` on the specific db you want (maybe not `postgres` db) or this function will not exist.

Answer (score 35):

Did you try using `SELECT PostGIS_version();`

Comment: Caution: `PostGIS_version()` outputs the major and minor version (e.g., "2.1"), but not the revision number (e.g., "2.1.4"), like `PostGIS_full_version()` and `PostGIS_Lib_Version()` do.

Answer (score 16):

`PostGIS_Lib_Version();` - returns the version number of the PostGIS library.

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/PostGIS_Lib_Version.html

Answer (score 12):

As the above people stated, select PostGIS_full_version(); will answer your question. On my machine, where I'm running PostGIS 2.0 from trunk, I get the following output:

```
postgres=# select PostGIS_full_version();
postgis_full_version                                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGIS="2.0.0alpha4SVN" GEOS="3.3.2-CAPI-1.7.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" GDAL="GDAL 1.8.1, released 2011/07/09" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS
(1 row)
```

You do need to care about the versions of PROJ and GEOS that are included if you didn't install an all-inclusive package - in particular, there's some brokenness in GEOS prior to 3.3.2 ([as noted in the postgis 2.0 manual](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/postgis_installation.html#id2589045)) in dealing with geometry validity.

Answer (score 10):

Other way to get the minor version is:

```sql
SELECT extversion
FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension
WHERE extname='postgis'
```

Comment: The above methods gave me `No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` but this one worked. The problem with the above not working was fixed by doing the `CREATE EXTENSION Postgis` from the console rather than from the db-migrate.js

Answer (score 2):

Using
SELECT PostGIS_version();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Using: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();