# Check postgis version without creating database

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833282/get-postgis-version) question which talks about using `SELECT PostGIS_full_version();` but this requires you have a database on which the postgis extension is installed.

I am using a fabric to write a program to check if postgis (above a particular version) is installed on a server and if not, install it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Every Postgres server contains 
a database called `postgres`.

You can connect to this database and query the [`pg_available_extensions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-available-extensions.html) or [`pg_available_extension_versions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-available-extension-versions.html) tables to see which versions of PostGIS are installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the postgres database (created when postgresql is installed) and execute

```sql
SELECT extversion
FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension
WHERE extname='postgis'
```

If you get a result, it will be the postgis version.

Comment: `pg_extension` only shows the extensions installed in that particular database. For the `postgres` database, there will generally be nothing in there besides `plpgsql`.

Comment: In all installations I can check, there was `postgis extension` in `postgres` database.

Comment: Someone/something must have created the extension manually; it shouldn't be installed there by default.